# Create an hierarchical from an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following

```
Array
(
    [1298650982] => Array
        (
            [genre] => Action
            [date] => 90s
            [rate] =>; 4
            [title] => Braveheart
        )

    [1298651271] => Array
        (
            [genre] => Action
            [date] => 90s
            [rate] => 3
            [title] => Top Gun
        )

)
```

and am trying to build a hierarchical system where it would return something like this

- Action

  - 90s
  - Rate: 4
  - Braveheart
  - Rate :3
  - Top Gun

basically combine the arrays where they have similar values.
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through your array and build a new array for your values. Something like:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    $result[$item['genre']][$item['date']][$key] = array(
        'title' => $item['title'],
        'rate' => $item['rate']
    );
}
```

Would give you:

```
Array
(
    [Action] => Array
        (
            [90s] => Array
                (
                    [1298650982] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Braveheart
                            [rate] => 4
                        )

                    [1298651271] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Top Gun
                            [rate] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

A little hard to tell from your question as to whether that was the type of formatting that you wanted. But you should be able to adjust it from here to get it to what you want.

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much sir. You helped me out a lot. I couldn't quiet keep the indenting going with the stackoverflow styling tools

Comment: Not a problem. Try it as a code block. If you edit your question and look at how the first array is indented you should be able to work it out. Use the preview box underneath to see how it'll look as well.